# SignalR with different chat rooms

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I got exercise that i need to make one chat room with SingalR in which i write the message and two chat rooms that on switch of a button i decide to which room it will  broadcast the message, i`m pretty new to this SingalR stuff, though i would like to get help in this, this what i did so far

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {


        public void Send(string name, string message, string connID)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            //  Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
          //  Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);

            Clients.Client(connID).broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }

    }
```

//the cshtml view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
}
<h2>Chat</h2>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message" />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
    <input type="radio"  id="family" value="family" /> Family
    <input type="radio" id="friends" value="friends" /> Friends
    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
    <ul id="discussion"></ul>
</div>
@section scripts {
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };

            chat.client.
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val(), $.connection.hub.id);
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [SignalR Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups)

Comment: yes, indeed, after some research i realised that i nedd groups, any help how i send message to different groups?

Comment: The first parameter in the method is the group name so you can send to as many as you want `Clients.Group(groupName)`

Comment: how i find the groupname in the client?

Comment: you don't need to find it you send it from the client when you send the message.

Comment: thanks, found this out